# Retrieve text containing a variable and associate the value to it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I think this is a really odd question but I will try anyway; here the scenario:

1. Table with 2 columns (id int, text nvarchar(max))
2. The value of one text fields defined as following

   `'Value of the variable is ' + @var`
3. Then i execute this part of code

   `DECLARE @var INT = 100
           ,@text NVARCHAR(MAX)`

   `SELECT @text = text FROM tbl WHERE id = 1`

   `SELECT @text`

The output of this is exactly what i stored in the table " 'Value of the variable is ' + @var "; my question is the following, is there any way to reinterpret/parse the string inside the @text variable as if it were like:

`SET @text = 'Value of the variable is ' + @var`

`SELECT @text`

An thus the output will be something like " Value of the variable is 100 ".

Thank you for any helpful advice,

F.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you want to achieve.. You might wanna cast the `INT` to `VARCHAR` btw. So would you like to get `SELECT @text = text + CAST(@var AS varchar(10)) FROM tbl WHERE id = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
select replace(@text, '@var', @var)
```

I can't tell if the `+` is in the string.  When I do this, the string looks like:

```
SET @text = 'Value of the variable is @var';
```

And the variable gets substituted directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` method to substitute values in a string:

```
declare @val int = 100
declare @str nvarchar(100) = '''Value of the variable is'' + @var'

-- output string as it is
select @str as output

-- replace the @var
select replace(@str,'@var',cast(@val as nvarchar(10))) as output
```

You could tidy this up with removing quotes and other noise

```
-- replace the variable
set @str = replace(@str,'@var',cast(@val as nvarchar(10)))

-- remove quotes
set @str = replace(@str,'''','')

-- remove +
select replace(@str,'+ ','') as output
```

You could combine these into a single call, with some ugly sql like this:

```
-- roll them in to a single replace 
select replace(
               replace(
                       replace(@str,'@var',cast(@val as nvarchar(10))),
                       '''',''),
               '+ ','') as output
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use dynamic code:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(200)= '''Value of the variable is ''  + @var';
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(10) = 100

DECLARE @results NVARCHAR(300) = '';

--Prepare dynamic sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT @results = ' + @text

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N' @var NVARCHAR(10), @results VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @var=@var, @results=@results OUTPUT;

PRINT @results;
```